# How to write event class for a customized listener?

Tags: java, events, character, listeners

I'm making a game in Java where I need some character to listen on a time event which is handled in another class.

I been using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898485/java-events-and-event-listeners) to make my own listener for it.

So fare i have defined an interface like this:

```
public interface TimeListener {
    public void onTick(TimeEvent event);
}
```

And the the TimeEvent like this:

```
public class TimeEvent {
    private int time;

    public TimeEvent(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}
```

In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898485/java-events-and-event-listeners) he wrote that the EatEvent could be as simple as a wrapper class for the food. I was not quite how to do that. Does my TimeEvent cover this?

My TimeEvent, unlike the EatEvent, also needs to give the time along from the Time class to the listeners. Is this the proper way to send the time along?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use Observer design pattern for it